# Custom meaningful error message for Zend RegEx Validator

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm validating a text field in my form as follows:

```
 $name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');

 $name->setLabel('First Name:')
      ->setRequired(true)
      ->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_StringTrim())
      ->addValidator('regex',true,array('/^[(a-zA-Z0-9)]+$/'))
      ->addErrorMessage('Please enter a valid first name');
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is - how can i display a meaningful error message? 
Eg: If first name is 'XYZ-', how can i display '- is not allowed in first name.'

Is there a way I can access what character the regex is failing for?
Would you recommend something else altogether?

I thought about writing a custom validator but the regex is pretty simple, so I don't see the point. 
I couldn't find a decent documentation for the zend 'regex' validator anywhere.

If I don't override the default error message, I simple get something like :
';;;hhbhbhb' does not match against pattern '/^[(a-zA-Z0-9)]+$/' - which I obviously don't want to display to the user.

I'd appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about telling the user in layman's terms what your restrictions are? Like

```
Error: Only the letters A to Z and numbers are allowed.
```

(Which leads me to the question why first names can contain numbers...)

Comment: Hi, this was just an example...could be any field (not necessarily first name) but is an example of the problem im facing thats all..

Comment: I believe he was asking *how* to set a message, not what message to set.

Comment: @Marcus Downing: I don't think so. She already knows how to set a message (see her sample code), and she wanted to find out how to generate a message that is "tailored" to the user's input. Which I advised against.

Answer (score 16):

For your custom error message(s) in zend standart validators just pass the `messages` array to the validator while instantiating. It's an array, which keys are error types (see further), and values - error messages.

```
->addValidator('regex', true, 
                       array(
                           'pattern'=>'/^[(a-zA-Z0-9)]+$/', 
                           'messages'=>array(
                               'regexNotMatch'=>'Your own custom error message'
                           )
                       )
)
```

To see error keys for other error types of chosen validator you may refer to it's source code.
For `regex` validator it's located at  {Zend Framework Library}/Zend/Validate/Regex.php .

**Good luck** in validating :).