# Zend form_element add validator with custom error message

Tags: php, zend-framework, validation

I have a Zend_Form_element:

```
$text=new Zend_Form_Element_Text('text');
```

I added a regex validator to it:

```
$text->addValidator('regex', false, array('/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/'));
```

How could I set a customized error message for the validator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add custom validation error messages if you know what specific error codes the validator provides. In case of regex, I believe it gives an "regexNotMatch" error, so for this particular case, you could use:

```
$text->addValidator('regex', false, array(
    '/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/',
    'messages'=>array(
    'regexNotMatch'=>'There was some random custom error'
    )    
));
```

For more information, have a look [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html).

> Some developers may wish to provide custom error messages for a validator. The $options argument of the Zend_Form_Element::addValidator() method allows you to do so by providing the key 'messages' and mapping it to an array of key/value pairs for setting the message templates. You will need to know the error codes of the various validation error types for the particular validator

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450728/zend-regex-validator-error-message-issue) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257247/having-problems-with-zend-validator-regex-for-a-number-interger-or-optional-flo)